# How to share resource between two networks?

Tags: networking, wifi, portforwarding, adsl

I am building a home office network.

Due to physical limitation of my environment, I have setup my Wifi network under two routers in two different rooms.

DSL <------> Router 1 (Room 1)  < ---- RJ45  192.168.1.105 --> Router 2 (Room 2)

Following is the current setting for bother Router

**Router 1**

IP: 192.168.1.1

DHCP Range: 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.255

Facilities connected:

- DSL Wall point - Connected to internet (NBN).
- Printer
- Smart TV
- Mobile
- Other Desktop

**Router 2**

IP: 192.168.2.1

DHCP Range: 192.168.2.0 - 192.168.2.255

Facilities connected:

- Laptop
- Smart TV
- Mobile

Gateway: 192.168.1.1

I can connect to internet from Router 2. However, I am not able to use Router 2 to access to the Smart TV and Printer that is connected to Router 1 .

Both routers does NOT support Access Point Mode. Therefore, they are connected Via RJ45 Ethernet.

Anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because that router uses NAT/NAPT for the lack of IP address and the protection of internal network. Normally, we use four types like Full Cone NAT, Restricted NAT, Port Restricted NAT and Symmetric NAT. They have different features, but they have a common feature: none of connection can be established from the outer side.

That means you can connect to outer side from inside, and then establish a connection, then the bidirection communication can work well. But if you firstly want to handshake from the outer side, it will fail.

So, here is something we called NAT traversal or NAT pounch hole to make some specifi internal IP/port can be connect from outside.

For your circumstances, the easiest way is to try upnp or nat-pmp if your router supports them. If not, it's relatively hard for you to simply connect them. Maybe you can try STUN/TURN/ICE, but I think you will not like them cause it's relatively hard.